# Serialization issue with CommonsMultipartFile

Tags: jackson

my bean has folliwng snippet

```
@JsonIgnore
private List<MultipartFile> fileData;

@XmlTransient
public List<MultipartFile> getFileData() {
    return fileData;
}
```

I et this error upon a file upload

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and 
no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) 
(through reference chain: com.commands.MyCommand["fileData"]->
java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile["fileItem"]->
org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"])
```

I read that if i used `@JsonIgnore` then I may be able to avoid this error, but this does not seem to be the case for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even though my getter was marked with `@XMlTransient`, seemed the jackson was still looking for `@JsonIgnore` and upon adding it, things worked as expected.